# How can I color labels of phylogenetic tree generated with plot.phylo (Biostrings) by a dataframe value and add a color legend?

Tags: r, phylogeny

I used the msa and Biostings packages to generate a phylogenetic tree plotting different viruses. Now, I would like to color the virus names by their genus. This is the code I have so far that works to generate the tree:

```
fas <- data.frame(Name =c("Hepatitis C virus genotype 2","Hepatitis C virus genotype 6","Hog cholera virus","Tree shrew pegivirus"),
                 Genus = c("Hepacivirus","Hepacivirus","Pestivirus","Pegivirus"),
                 seq = c("CSPEEEKLPINPLSNSLLRYHNKVYCTTTKSASLRAKKVTFDRMQVLDSYYDSVLKDIKLAASKVTARLL
TMEEACQLTPPHSARSKYGFGAKEVRSLSGRAVNHIKSVWKDLLEDSETPIPTTIMAKNEVFCVDPTKGG
KKAARLIVYPDLGVRVCEKMALYDITQKLPQAVMGASYGFQYSPAQRVEFLLKAWAEKKDPMGFSYDTRC
FDSTVTERDIRTEESIYRACSLPEEAHTAIHSLTERLYVGGPMFNSKGQTCGYRRCRASGVLTTSMGNTI
TCYVKALAACKAAGIIAPTMLVCGDDLVVISESQGTEEDERNLRAFTEAMTRYSAPPGDPPRPEYDLELI
TSCSSNVSVALGPQGRRRYYLTRDPTTPIARAAWETVRHSPVNSWLGNIIQYAPTIWARMVLMTHFFSIL
MAQDTLDQNLNFEMYGAVYSVSPLDLPAIIERLHGLDAFSLHTYTPHELTRVASALRKLGAPPLRAWKSR
ARAVRASLISRGGRAAVCGRYLFNWAVK","CAAEEEKLPINPLSNSLIRHHNMVYSTTSRSAGLRQKKVTFDRLQVVDQHYQDVLKEIKLRASTVHARLL
STEEACSLTPPHSARSRYGYGARDVRSHTSKAVKHIDSVWEDLLEDNATPIPTTIMAKNEVFCVDPSKGG
RKPARLIVYPDLSVRVCEKMALYDVTQKLPKTVMGSAYGFQYSPSQRVEYLLKMWRSKKTPMGFSYDTRC
FDSTVTERDIRTEEDIYQSCQLDPTARKAISSLTERLYCGGPMFNSKGESCGYRRCRASGVLTTSLGNTL
TCYLKAQAACRAANIKNFDMLVCGDDLVVICESAGVQEDVVALRAFTDAMIRYSAPPGDAPQPTYDLELI
TSCSSNVSVAHDGTGQRYYYLTRDCTTPLARAAWETARHTPVNSWLGNIIMYAPTIWVRMVLMTHFFSIL
QCQEQLEAALNFDMYGVTYSVTPLDLPAIIQRLHGMAAFSLHGYSPTELNRVGASLRKLGAPPLRAWRHR
ARAVRAKLIAQGGKAAICGKYLFNWAVK","NEWIIGKIKYQGNLRTKHMLNPGKVAEQLLREGHKHNVYNKTIGSVMTATGIRLEKLPVVRAQTDTTNFH
QAIRDKIDKEENLQTPGLHKKLMEVFNALKRPELESSYDAVEWEELERGINRKGAAGFFERKNIGEILDS
EKNKVEEIIDNLRRGRNIKYYETAIPKNEKRDVNDDWTAGDFVDEKKPRVIQYPEAKTRLAITKVMYKWV
KQKPVVIPGYEGKTPLFQIFDKVKKEWDQFQNPVAVSFDTKAWDTQVTTKDLELIKDIQKYYFKKKWHKF
IDTLTMHMSEVPVISADGEVYIRKGQRGSGQPDTSAGNSMLNVLTMVYAFCEATGVPYKSFDRVAKIHVC
GDDGFLITERALGEKFASKGVQILYEAGKPQKITEGDKMKVAYQFDDIEFCSHTPIQVRWSDNTSSYMPG
RNTTTILAKMATRLDSSGERGTIAYEKAVAFSFLLMYSWNPLIRRICLLVLSTELQVKPGKSTTYYYEGD
PISAYKEVIGHNLFDLKRTSFEKLAKLNLSMSVLGAWTRHTSKRLLQDCVNMGVKEGNWLVNADRLVSSK
TGNRYIPGEGHTLQGRHYE","WSGAPIAVQEPKRPPVTRPLTAQLRARADQVYVTQPQDIYRRLQKVTIEQVEADVDEAFRDAYNLAKAKA
SRILSPQWSYEEAVAKVKPRSARGHVANITVSDLQTSRGRRIVEEARDGILSGTLEAPFMLRPKSEVFPN
TKGTRKPPRLICYPSLEFRVAEKMILGDPSLVAKAVMGPAYGFQYPPHQRAQVLASMWKSKKTPICYTLD
GVCFDSTITEADIEREGEIFAAASSDPAAVRALHRYYAKGPMVGADGLVVGVRHCRASGTLTTSSGNSIT
CYIKVSAACRKAKIPNPSFLIHGDDVVVIAEKDEEDHCDALAAALRSYGYACTPEVHADLSTAESCSATL
DTVRTVRGIKPVLSTDMRRGLGRVLAEYGDPVGTAWGYTISYPTHPIVCYILLPVLLQTALNNGDGPDQD
VTIDVRGNTLKLPLSSLGNALRSLHGPDILCVTGRSATVMQQTAQCLQFFGMRGIG"))

library(seqinr)

seqs = as.list(dplyr::pull(fas, seq))
names = dplyr::pull(fas, `Name`)
fasta <- write.fasta(seqs,names,"fasta")

#load FASTA and convert to string set
if (!require("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
  install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install("Biostrings")
fas <- readAAStringSet("fasta")

seqs = as.list(dplyr::pull(flavi_AAseq_polypro, seq.text))
names = dplyr::pull(flavi_AAseq_polypro, `Name`)
write.fasta(seqs,names,"Desktop/fasta")

#install Biostrings/msa
if (!require("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
  install.packages("BiocManager")

BiocManager::install("Biostrings", force = TRUE)
BiocManager::install("msa")
library(msa)
library(Biostrings)

#load in FASTA file and convert to FASTA to a string set (special data type that is used to annotate sequnece data) 
fas.str <- readAAStringSet("fasta")

#Build multiple sequence alinment (MSA) and get genetic distances
#while running, it will show message "use default substitution matrix"
fas_align <- msa(fas.str,method = "ClustalW")
class(fas_align) <- "AAMultipleAlignment"
fas_align_seqinr <- msaConvert(fas_align, type = "seqinr::alignment")
fas_dist <- seqinr::dist.alignment(fas_align_seqinr, matrix = "identity")

#make a phylogeny tree, color tips by variable (i.e. genus)
library(ape)
tree <- nj(fas_dist)
plot.phylo(tree, main = "Phylo tree Test", use.edge.length = F,
           cex = 0.5)
```

I tried adding the tip.color() command to color by the genus but the color blocking is (I think) instead being applied sequentially. So, whatever virus is first in the df is assigned green coloring, whatever virus is second in the df is assigned red, and so on.

```
plot.phylo(tree, main = "Phylo tree Test", use.edge.length = F,
           cex = 0.5, 
           tip.color = c("green", "red", "blue", df$Genus))
```

[What I am seeing with this command...not sure what the other black/red/green colors refer to (I think it has to do with branching) but they are also not by genus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3P47.png)

I would like to be able to assign colors based on the values in the Genus column of the df and also have a legend.

Comment: What are virus names in your Genus column?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I updated with all the code I used to generate a smaller version of my phylogeny tree and the data frame with the genus information

Answer (score 0):

```
## Generating a random tree
some_tree <- rtree(20)

## Generating a set of groups (e.g. genera) for the tips
some_factor <- sample(c(1,2,3), 20, replace = TRUE)
names(some_factor) <- some_tree$tip.label
```

In your case, these factors could be attributing each tip names to their respective genera. For example, they could come from your Genus column.

```
## Plotting the tree
plot.phylo(some_tree, main = "Phylo tree Test", use.edge.length = F,
           cex = 0.5, 
           tip.color = c("green", "red", "blue")[some_factor])
```

The `c("green", "red", "blue")[some_factor]` bit attributes each of the colours to the levels of each of the tips (i.e creating a vector like: `"red", "blue", "green", "red", "red", etc`).